# Generating list of dates with repetition intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a program where the main feature is an event calendar. There are people and events in the database, and it tracks attendance at individual events.

On the event side, I want to be able to provide an option for repeating events to be generated. If an event is repeating, the user provides the following information:

1) Event start date
2) Event end date
3) Days that repeat (eg, Thursdays)
4) Repeat interval (Weekly, bi-weekly, and monthly)

All of this information is inserted into a table, "events", which then causes a trigger to execute. The trigger uses this info to generate records in another table, "event_instances", which contains a record for each instance of a given event (each day the event occurs on). Event attendance is then tracked based on each instance.

In order to maximize performance, I've been working with an approach of creating a temporary table, filtering it down to only the dates I need, and then inserted it into the event_instance table. This is a great approach because of its ability to perform the whole operation in 1-2 seconds.

My problem now comes down to the repeat interval. Before I go there, here's the sql code I'm using to generate the temporary table. This formula creates a table of 100,000 dates between the @start_date and @end_date. @start_date and @end_date are temporary values, in the final implementation this will be in a function with two date parameters for those values.

```
set @start_date = '2015-9-20';
set @end_date = '2016-1-17';

select * from
(select  @start_date + interval ((a.a) + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) day this_date
from 
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as a 
join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as b 
join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as c
join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as d
join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as e) v
where this_date <= date(@end_date);
```

This generates a table containing every date between @start_date and @end_date. To narrow to a weekly repeat is easy, all I need to do is add (for weekly on Thursdays in the example):

```
and dayofweek(this_date) = 5
```

The thing is, I can't figure out how to do bi-weekly or monthly filtering from here. That's the final piece of making all of this work.

Thank so much in advance.

Comment: This is a notoriously difficult problem to solve generally. Read this book. http://www.worldcat.org/title/dreaming-in-code-two-dozen-programmers-three-years-4732-bugs-and-one-quest-for-transcendent-software/oclc/70174970

Answer (score 1):

For monthly, you would use the `day()` function:

```
where day(this_date) = 5
```

For the 5th of the month.

For biweekly (every two weeks), you should probably subtract some canonical date and use mod:

```
where mod(datediff(this_date, '2001-01-01'), 14) = 5
```

For one of the days of the week, every other week.